# Bluetooth turning on automatically after everytime I boot my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, dell, battery, inspiron

I have **Dell Inspiron 14 5402** and I installed **Ubuntu 20.04** on it. Even after turning off bluetooth, on next boot, it turns on automatically. I am worried about battery draining caused by it. Earlier I had **Pop OS** and it was funtioning properly on it. Any solution or is it a bug?

Comment: No solution, but just to add I find this happens too (20.10, HP Omen Laptop) even if I just suspend/wake. I never use Bluetooth on my laptop so I turn off Bluetooth and the PC goes into `Aeroplane Mode` (I use wired network). Suspend/wake and PC is now out of `Aeroplane Mode` and Bluetooth is back on. So Following this question...

Comment: I'm facing the same problem... (other than many others in this Ubuntu version...) No way found for now

Answer (score -1):

I used

> sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service

Comment: It doesn't work. Also after each switch on/off of the wifi it turns on automatically